# cannot add Windows 2016 to existing domain. Both domain and tree funtional levels are 2003.

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I am unable to add my new 2016 server to my domain. Says the functional level is 2000 on 2016 but on actual server both domain and forest levels are 2003.[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Iln.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps you could re-title and reword your question to make it more accurate and relevant. What you're actually doing is trying to add a Windows Server 2016 Domain Controller, not just simply joining the server to the domain.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you must have all domain controllers running 2008 or greater in order to add a 2016 server to a domain with a functional level of 2003.2003 has been deprecated. You should upgrade all servers and raise the functional level to 2008 at minimum.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/windows-server-2016-functional-levels

Comment: George, Thanks for responding. The 2016 server joined the domain without a hitch. I am trying to add active directory role. Upgrading to 2008 is not possible with current business systems.

Comment: It will not allow it to become a domain controller unless all other domain controllers on the network are at least server 2008. This is because the replication technology used in 2003 is not supported under 2016.